# nginx subdomain proxy pass not working

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I am trying to redirect a subdomain on my website. For now, I have added the following block to the file at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name notebook.mysite.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0;
        }
    }
```

This should make visiting notebook.mysite.com the same as visiting mysite.com and show the homepage. Eventually, I will add a port so the location block contains `proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:12345;` However, when I visit `http://notebook.mysite.com` my browser gives me the error

```
This site can’t be reached

notebook.mysite.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

Anybody know why this is, or at the very least how I would go about troubleshooting it?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not a valid IP to connect to. You want to change it to something like `http://localhost` or `http://example.com`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add an A record with my host, Digital Ocean, for this to work properly. I added an A record with a * to redirect all subdomains to my server.